# Offset anchors for autoscrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm currently using the code from css-tricks to perform the auto scroll functions to my anchors here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

What do I need to do offset the "top of the page"? Basically I would like to have the page stop about 150px from the anchor location..

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
```

to:

```
var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 150;
```

This will push it up 150 pixels further than the top of where you are targeting.

With regards to the hash:

Change this: `location.hash = target;`

To:

```
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, target);
}
else {
    location.hash = target;
}
```

Comment: That's what I figured, which I tried before posting here. When I change that, it scrolls to that point then snaps to the position as if it wasn't changed..

Comment: @Reuben to remove that jump comment out this line: `location.hash = target;`  Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/gauSh/

Comment: that worked! however, the url doesn't change when clicked now.. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It should be `"#"+target`. (Same thing as mine)

Comment: @lucuma and I added jquery tabs to this page, and now it's scrolling funky.. new issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015824/jquery-tabs-added-to-code-makes-auto-scroll-vertical-scroll-past-anchors
thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 1):

The part that messes up is here:

```
location.hash = target;
```

Remove it, and use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method) instead:

```
history.pushState({}, "", "#"+target);
```

If `pushState` is not supported, then you can use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js).

Comment: That's identical to my answer, I'm changing targetOffset.

Comment: Maybe this will work? I don't know, but it should. (I know both answers are the same, but this worths a try.)

Comment: yea.. same thing:
"That's what I figured, which I tried before posting here. When I change that, it scrolls to that point then snaps to the position as if it wasn't changed.."

Comment: @Reuben - It should be `"#"+target"`, not just `target`. And you can upvote both answers if you want to.

Comment: @Derek and I added jquery tabs to this page, and now it's scrolling funky.. new issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015824/jquery-tabs-added-to-code-makes-auto-scroll-vertical-scroll-past-anchors
thanks for helping :D