# Jquery tabs added to code makes auto scroll (vertical) scroll past anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, jquery-tabs

I have set up a autoscroll page using the css-tricks code for smooth scrolling:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

It has always worked great, and I have just added jquery tabs to some of the content which now makes it scroll past the main anchors that are below the tabs.

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qR5bm/

Why is this  happening and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that after you apply the scrolling you are hiding a bunch of items. For some reason it seems to be interfering with the calculations.

If you move the smooth scrolling code below the tab functions, it will work fine:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/qR5bm/1/

Comment: I'd like to investigate further to see the actual reason but I don't have the time right now.. At least you can see how to fix it.

Comment: Oh yeah, one more thing. Try clicking different buttons multiple times fast, and the animation won't stop until every animation is done. That's why you should put `.stop()` before `animation()`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qR5bm/2/

Comment: @lucuma - Try clicking `Story` `How` `Story` `How` `Story` `How`... (very fast) in your demo, then you will see what's wrong.